# Cannot build project for Xbox, using XNA

Tags: xna, c#

I'm trying to build a project for Xbox, and when I try to Package as an XNA Creator's Club Game I receive the following errors:

The best overloaded method match for 'Pong.MessageBoxScreen.MessageBoxScreen(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game, string)' has some invalid arguments.

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game'

Argument 2: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'string'

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for when the Unlock Game menu entry is selected.
    /// </summary>
    void UnlockMenuEntrySelected(object sender, PlayerIndexEventArgs e)
    {
 #if XBOX
        try
        {
            Guide.ShowMarketplace(e.PlayerIndex);
        }
        catch (GamerPrivilegeException gamerPrivilegeException)
        {
            const string message = "Please use Xbox Live account.";

            MessageBoxScreen promptForPurchase = new MessageBoxScreen(message, false);
            ScreenManager.AddScreen(promptForPurchase, e.PlayerIndex);
        }
 #else
        const string message = "Unlock Full Game (Xbox Only)";
        MessageBoxScreen unlockMessageBox = new MessageBoxScreen(Game, message,      false);
        ScreenManager.AddScreen(unlockMessageBox, e.PlayerIndex);

 #endif
    }
```

Everything within the #if XBOX area is grayed out, I suppose because it is surrounded by that tag.

What do you think is suddenly causing these issues, and how can I correct it?

Comment: I see code, but no error messages.

Comment: What error? Please edit post.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit "post" while I was in the middle of writing the post :p. I've since added it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the exception, it appears this line is at fault:

`MessageBoxScreen promptForPurchase = new MessageBoxScreen(message, false);`

You'll see that the error message tells you exactly what is wrong. You are passing arguments that are invalid for that constructor. You need to pass a `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game` object as the first argument and a `String` as the second argument.

Comment: That was exactly it. 

I don't remember ever changing this constructor, but when I went back and compared it to the GSM sample, it appears that I must have at some point. Thank you!